# How to increase the height of an html text box input with starting text align from top-left?

Tags: css, html

I want to this passege written from up to down.

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" style="width: 50%; height: 150px;">
```

[image]

Comment: Do you wants multiline text? If yes then use `textarea` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use textarea instead of input.
you can find more information and examples here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

here is an example:

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="50">
    Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. there isn't way to use input?

Comment: If you want multiline, then no.. there are some workaround to make text align on top in the input field but the user cannot enter more than one line into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a textarea element instead of a textbox?